# how is java deep copy possible in this situation

Tags: java, performance

**NOTE**: I have looked at different places including stackoverflow and have not found solution to this.

**PROBLEM**:

```
class Animal{

AnimalGroup animalGroup;

}

class AnimalGroup{

List<Animal> animalList;

}

class MainProgram{

// Map<groupRank, animalGroup>
Map<Integer, AnimalGroup> rankedAnimalGroups;

}
```

Note: As it is apparent one Animal can belong to only one AnimalGroup.

I want to deep copy the map *rankedAnimalGroups*.

**Case1: Cloning**

I will make my Animal and AnimalGroup Cloneable.

Clone method in AnimalGroup

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    AnimalGroup clonedAnimalGroup = (AnimalGroup)super.clone();
    for(Animal animal: animalList)
       clonedAnimalGroup.addAnimal(animal.clone);

    return clonedAnimalGroup;
}
```

Clone method in Animal

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    Animal clonedAnimal = (Animal)super.clone();
    clonedAnimal.animalGroup = animalGroup.clone(); 
}
```

This will end up in a cycle of AnimalGroup calling Animal and reverse.

**Case2: copyConstructor**

HashMap doesnot support deep copy constructor

**Suggested Solution**

I can use constructor for Animal, inside clone method of AnimalGroup, as follows

Clone method in AnimalGroup

```
protected Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    AnimalGroup clonedAnimalGroup = (AnimalGroup)super.clone();
    for(Animal animal: animalList)
       clonedAnimalGroup.addAnimal(new Animal(animal, this));

    return clonedAnimalGroup;
}
```

Constructor in Animal

```
public Animal(Animal other, AnimalGroup animalGroup)
{
  this.animalGroup = animalGroup;
  ...
}
```

**Question**
Is there any better solution for deep copy in such case.

**Edit1**

Data size is too large for serialization related approach.

**Edit2**

I can not include external libs etc for copying in my project

Comment: Kind of duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049222/java-hashmap-deep-copy

Comment: The problem in above question is not how to copy hashmap. It is about how to resolve the issue for recursive calling to each other of the two classes in their clone methods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can give yourself the helper methods you need to perform a deep copy.  When deep-copying an `Animal`, obtain a deep copy of its group instead and return the member of that group corresponding to the `Animal` being copied; when deep-copying a group, obtain new copies of the members without assigning them any group, add these new copies to a new list, assign that list as the group for each element, then return the new list.  Doing so will require that the group have access to a special constructor that does not assign a group right away.

There are other similar variations on this theme.

Comment: Thats a good answer. Your answer would have been perfect for a situation where Animal and AnimalGroup would have one-on-one relation, instead of List<Animal>.
Anyways, thanks I will try this.

Just curious, did you come up with the answer just now or is this like a normal practice in such situations?

Comment: Should work even in one-to-many case.  You just need a `deepCopyExceptGroup` available in the `Animal` class.  I just came up with it on the fly but this type of algorithm arises all the time with circular data.  It reminds me of something I learned about in a programming languages course from undergraduate school.  I'll see if I can find the reference.

Comment: A reference would be great, thanks. Between, I understand that your solution will be good for one-to-many as well, in fact I will use a similar variation, I was just pointing about one-on-one case.

Answer (score 1):

You can [serialize-deserialize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64036/how-do-you-make-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-java) the object which is robust way of **deep cloning**

Comment: Ofcourse there are efficient ways of doing it using 3rd party marshallers/unmarshallers