# java - how to do deep copy of hashmap

Tags: java

How to deep copy hashmap? I wanna make a copy of hashmap. When I change the keys and values in the copy, the original hashmap doesn't change. I cannot find a solution to solve this problem in the Internet. The function of putall() doesn't work.

```
HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>> map1 ;
HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>> map2 = new HashMap<OWLClass, Set<OWLClass>>();
```

I tried

```
for(OWLClass map1.keySet()){
        map2.put(a, map1.get(a));
    }
```

and

```
map2.putAll(map1);
```

Both these methonds don't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java HashMap - deep copy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13049222/java-hashmap-deep-copy)

Comment: *When I change the keys and values in the copy, the original hashmap doesn't change.* Well, that's good, right?

Comment: You need one more step `for(OWLClass map1.keySet()){
        map2.put(a, new HashSet<>(map1.get(a)));
    }`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thank you so much!!!