# Java: LinkedHashMaps overlaps over themselves

Tags: java, linkedhashmap

I want to create a copy of linked hash map and then I want to remove all values (from the List) instead of the first entry. Here is what I got:

```
LinkedHashMap<String, List<Value>> facetsInCategoriesCopy = new LinkedHashMap<>(facetsInCategories);

if (!facets.equals("something")) {
    for (List<Value> value : facetsInCategoriesCopy.values()) {
        if (value.size() > 1) {
            int nbrOfElements = value.size();
            for (int i = nbrOfElements-1; i > 0; i--) {
                value.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After this operation it turns out that facetsInCategories are modified too. Why? And how to solve the issue?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might have created a copy of `LinkedHashMap`, but what about copies of the `List<Value>` objects? Remember, Java is pass by value and the value is the reference to objects.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to replace the value lists in the copy with new lists and add the first element of the corresponding list from the original?

Comment: Also, the clearing could be done more efficiently as `value.subList(1, value.size()).clear()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a 50 reputation to add a comment. See this answer [Assigning Hashmap to Hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296490/assigning-hashmap-to-hashmap)

Essentially, the copy constructor you used to make the new map has references to the mutable objects i.e. `facetsInCategories` and will update that as well when you update the `facetsInCategoriesCopy` map.

The solution would be to instead do a deep copy instead. I have added test code below, I used `String` instead of `Value`

```
  //Test for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27324315/
  public static void testStackO_Q_27324315() {

    Map<String, List<String>> facetsInCategories = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
    String[] values = new String[]{"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"};
    List<String> valuesList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(values));
    facetsInCategories.put("Test", valuesList);

    Map temp = Collections.unmodifiableMap(facetsInCategories);
    LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>> facetsInCategoriesCopy = (LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>)deepCopy(temp);

    String facets = "test_me";

    if (!facets.equals("something")) {
        for (List<String> value : facetsInCategoriesCopy.values()) {
            if (value.size() > 1) {
                int nbrOfElements = value.size();
                for (int i = nbrOfElements-1; i > 0; i--) {
                    value.remove(i);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(facetsInCategories);
    System.out.println(facetsInCategoriesCopy);
}

public static <K1, K2, V> Map<K1, List<V>> deepCopy(
      Map<K1, List<V>> original){

      Map<K1, List<V>> copy = new LinkedHashMap<K1, List<V>>();
      for(Map.Entry<K1, List<V>> entry : original.entrySet()){
          copy.put(entry.getKey(), new ArrayList<V>(entry.getValue()));
      }
      return copy;
  }
```