# What does <T extends mean?

Tags: java, generics

I have seen a method like shown below:

```
protected <T extends ABC> T save( T Acd, boolean en) {
```

What does it do? What is these type of method declarations called in Java?

Comment: Go through some tutorials. You can start with: - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html

Comment: I don't find it bad to ask how a construct is called! +1

Answer (score 49, accepted):

It is called a generic method. This whole concept is called "Generics" in Java. That declaration means T can be any type that is subclass of ABC.

Comment: Can I use any alphabet ? or only T is the only declaration type for mentioning it is a Generic method?

Comment: You can use any letter. T is an abbreviation for "Type" I think. In map structures <K, V> is used which means "Key" and "Value" type. So you are free to pick any letter. But I recommend picking one that makes sense. Also I'm not sure but it may not be restricted to letters, you may pick a word.Also there are wildcard types, you should check the documentation for more info.

Comment: You can use any legal identifier for a Generic type argument, but convention states it should be a capital letter.  See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900881/generic-type-parameter-naming-convention-for-java-with-multiple-chars.  Using a word is usually a bad idea because when you read something like `List<Blah>`  you can't tell if `Blah` is a class or a type parameter.

Answer (score 21):

Bounded Type Parameters:

There may be times when you'll want to restrict the kinds of types that are allowed to be passed to a type parameter. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what bounded type parameters are for.

To declare a bounded type parameter, list the type parameter's name, followed by the extends keyword, followed by its upper bound.
Example:

Following example illustrate how extends is used in a general sense to mean either "extends" (as in classes) or "implements" (as in interfaces). This example is Generic method to return the largest of three Comparable objects:

```
public class MaximumTest
{
   // determines the largest of three Comparable objects
   public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maximum(T x, T y, T z)
   {                      
      T max = x; // assume x is initially the largest       
      if ( y.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
         max = y; // y is the largest so far
      }
      if ( z.compareTo( max ) > 0 ){
         max = z; // z is the largest now                 
      }
      return max; // returns the largest object   
   }
   public static void main( String args[] )
   {
      System.out.printf( "Max of %d, %d and %d is %d\n\n", 
                   3, 4, 5, maximum( 3, 4, 5 ) );

       System.out.printf( "Maxm of %.1f,%.1f and %.1f is %.1f\n\n",
                   6.6, 8.8, 7.7, maximum( 6.6, 8.8, 7.7 ) );

       System.out.printf( "Max of %s, %s and %s is %s\n","pear",
         "apple", "orange", maximum( "pear", "apple", "orange" ) );
   }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
protected <T extends ABC> T save( T Acd, boolean en) {
    // ...
}
```

In this function, there are three places where the `T` appears

- **bounded type parameter**: `<T extends ABC>`
- **returned-type**: `T`
- **parameter**: `T Acd`

Based on those, I can answer your questions as following

> What does it do?

`save()` is a generic method that accepts two parameters and one of them has the type of `T` and returns a value of type `T`. `T` is a generic type, that is restricted to `ABC`. The scope of `T` is limited to `save()`.

> What is these type of method declarations called in Java?

IMO, the answer should be **bounded type parameters**, instead of **generics**. More about **generics** in Java, you can find [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).

One more question I would like to add by myself: ***Why do we want such thing?***

> There may be times when you want to restrict the types that can be used as type arguments in a parameterized type. For example, a method that operates on numbers might only want to accept instances of Number or its subclasses. This is what bounded type parameters are for [[1]](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html).

Answer (score 4):

This is a `generic` save method which excepts parameter T and boolean type where T must be upper bounded by ABC Class. ABC class or any subclass will be accepted.

Comment: think you meant 'expects'

Comment: This seems the most succinct answer, but to complete it more, the save method also returns Type T, that's why the T before the method name. Pretty obvious, but not at first glance and not after reading first few answers. Seemed like the method declaration was sprinkled with Ts resulting in some alien code.

Comment: "ABC" class also works. That's what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It means that you **must** send an `ABC` object or a child of `ABC`, no other classes allowed. Also, your `Acd` variable could use the methods in `ABC` class that are visible to the class that contians the `save` method.

This is useful when your `T` class extends interfaces. For example, you're creating a class that handles object array sorting and this class **must** implement tne `Comparable` interface, otherwise the array won't be allowed:

```
class Class1 implements Comparable<Class1> {
    //attributes, getters and setters...
    int x;

    //implementing the interface...
    public int compareTo(Class1 c1) {
        //nice implementation of compareTo
        return (this.x > c1.x)? 1 : (this.x < c1.x) ? 0 : -1;
    }
}

class Class2 {
    int x;
}

public class Sorter<T extends Comparable<T>> {

    public static void insertionSort(T[] array) {
        //good implementation of insertion sort goes here...
        //just to prove that you can use the methods of the Comparable interface...
        array[0].compareTo(array[1]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class1[] arrC1 = new Class1[5];
        Class2[] arrC2 = new Class2[5];
        //fill the arrays...
        insertionSort(arrC1); //good!
        insertionSort(arrC2); //compiler error!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This are generics. Generics with Type Bounds!

[See here for refernce](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is called generics in Java.

[Official explanation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html):

> In a nutshell, generics enable types (classes and interfaces) to be parameters when defining classes, interfaces and methods. Much like the more familiar formal parameters used in method declarations, type parameters provide a way for you to re-use the same code with different inputs. The difference is that the inputs to formal parameters are values, while the inputs to type parameters are types.

Informally:

Strongly typed languages like Java cause more errors show up at compile time instead of runtime. This is a good thing. But it causes code duplication. To mitigate this generics was added to Java.