# What is the point of T extends SomeClass?

Tags: java, generics

What is the difference with a method declaration like this:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> void doSomething(T obj)
{
    // Do something.
}
```

And this:

```
public void doSomething(SomeClass obj)
{
    // Do Something.
}
```

The way I see it, both of them are specifying that the object passed in *must* be a subclass of type `SomeClass`, so why bother with the generics at all in this instance?

Comment: I've often wondered this but didn't have enough courage to ask for fear of the dreaded {-1}s. So +1.

Comment: To say "java generics are completely useless" is a bold and incorrect statement. I don't deny they're flawed and fully featured, but that doesn't make them useless

Comment: Good god, sorry again, I don't seem to be able to read so I'm going home. In the case above, no point, but in other specific cases it can be useful, as per the answer from micha below. The implementation is for the developer and not the computer, for those cases when it happens to be useful for the person!

Comment: An example of when you would have to use this; [Returning a Collection<ChildType> from a method that specifies that it returns Collection<ParentType>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384015/returning-a-collectionchildtype-from-a-method-that-specifies-that-it-returns-c)

Comment: In the above example I don't see a difference, but if the return type was of type T, it would. In that case, client code wouldn't have to cast.

Comment: Very similar: [Type arguments in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934304/type-arguments-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does <T extends mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12928393/what-does-t-extends-mean)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In your case it doesn't make much difference.

But consider the following:

```
public <T extends SomeClass> void doSomething(List<T> obj)
```

In this case you could call the method the following ways:

```
obj.doSomething(new ArrayList<SubclassOfSomeClass>());
obj.doSomething(new ArrayList<SomeClass>());
```

If you would use

```
public void doSomething(List<SomeClass> obj)
```

You would only be able to do this:

```
obj.doSomething(new ArrayList<SomeClass>());
```

Comment: But `public void doSomething(List<? extends SomeClass> obj)` would be fine for this specific example.

Comment: @PaulBellora unless there was a second parameter `public <T extends SomeClass> void doSomething(List<T> obj, T bar)`

Comment: @ratchetfreak Right, that would be a better example.