# Typescript class declaration syntax with generics

Tags: typescript, generics, parameterization

Given the following:

```
interface Component {}
interface Composite<component extends Component> {
  getChildren(): component[];
}
class StackSegment implements Component {}
class Stack implements Composite<StackSegment> {
    getChildren(): StackSegment[] {
        return new Array<StackSegment>();
    }
}
```

Why does the following cause a compiler error?

```
class Bar<component extends Component = StackSegment, 
       composite extends Composite<component> = Stack> {
}
```

The error that I get (on Stack as the default value of composite) says that StackSegment is not assignable to type 'component'.

Comment: A default parameter does not add a constraint.  Do you want to be able to use `Bar` with other `Component` types?

Answer (score 1):

The problem, I think, is that the second type parameter depends on the first. I mean, if the first parameter is of type `P` then the second must be of type `Composite<P>` (assuming `P` implments `Component`).

But as you are assigning default types, you could do this:

```
let b = new Bar<P>();
```

Here I don't pass a second type parameter, so TypeScript assumes it is `Stack`. However, `Stack` does not extend `P`.

A default value for a type parameter not always enforces the type constraints, and so such a type cannot be declared.

Answer (score 1):

Note: in what follows I'm using short uppercase identifiers for type parameters, as the normal convention.  You can replace `CN` with `component` and `CS` with `composite` at your pleasure (but I'd recommend against using regular identifiers for generic type parameters)

---

I'm not sure what your use cases are, but default type parameters don't set constraints.  In your code,

```
class Bar<CN extends Component = StackSegment, 
       CS extends Composite<CN> = Stack> {  // error
}
```

The type parameter `CN` is not *required* to be `StackSegment`, and thus it's possible for `Stack` not to meet the constraint of `Composite<CN>`.  One way to deal with it is to make the composite just `Composite<CN>` instead of `Stack`:

```
class Bar<CN extends Component = StackSegment, 
       CS extends Composite<CN> = Composite<CN>> {  // okay
}
```

If you *really* want to see the default as `Stack` (e.g., if `Stack` has some extra methods that just `Composite<CN>` doesn't), then you can do this:

```
class Bar<CN extends Component = StackSegment, 
       CS extends Composite<CN> = Stack & Composite<CN>> {  // okay
}
```

since `Stack & Composite<StackSegment>` is the same structural type as `Stack`.  But again, I don't know your use case.  As of now, you get stuff like:

```
interface OtherComponent extends Component {
    thingy: string;
}

class OtherComposite implements Composite<OtherComponent> {
    getChildren(): OtherComponent[] {
        throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    }
}

new Bar(); // Bar<StackSegment, Stack> as desired
new Bar<OtherComponent, OtherComposite>(); // also makes sense

// but this is a Bar<OtherComponent, Stack & Composite<OtherComponent>>
new Bar<OtherComponent>(); // wha?
// which is weird.
```

Do you ever intend to use just one default parameter?  If not, maybe there's a better way to represent the generics.  But without more use case information I wouldn't know how to advise you.

Good luck.

---

EDIT:  An ugly syntax that works the way I think you want is to specify both types in one parameter, like this:

```
class Bar<CC extends [Component, Composite<CC[0]>]=[StackSegment, Stack],
    CN extends CC[0] = CC[0],
    CS extends CC[1] = CC[1]> {    
}
```

In the above, `CC` is a two-tuple of types with the constraint you want (the second parameter must be compatible with `Composite<>` of the first parameter), and it defaults to the pair `[StackSegment, Stack]` as desired.  (The `CN` and `CS` types are just there for convenience so you don't need to use `CC[0]` for the component type and `CC[1]` for the composite type).

Now the behavior is something like this:

```
new Bar(); // CN is StackSegment and CS is Stack, as desired
new Bar<[OtherComponent, OtherComposite]>(); // also makes sense
```

But you can't easily break it like before:

```
new Bar<[OtherComponent]>(); // error
new Bar<[OtherComponent, Stack]>(); // error
```

Okay, good luck again!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughtful and thorough response. I will cogitate. Before I do, I wanted to ask, having been writing code in Typescript for about 3 months now, why one would use one or two letter identifiers for parameterized types when they are often used throughout the code? I would think that more reasonable names would be infinitely preferable. In regard to your "ugly syntax", I am compelled to say "yuck". So I think we're in agreement. It's ugly. That having been said, it's amazing how many things one can do in Typescript that are not immediately obvious.

Comment: I think that convention is common across languages with generics.  Here's a [question about generics in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900881/generic-type-parameter-naming-convention-for-java-with-multiple-chars) whose answer is probably the same for TypeScript.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the line of code that causes the compiler error as follows:

```
class Bar<component extends Component = StackSegment, 
    composite extends Composite<Component> = Stack> {}
```

eliminates the error.

Now the question is, will it work as expected when overridden.

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. Calling getChildren() on composite returns Component[], not StackSegment[].